# When to pull from Docker repo and when from Git repo and then build?

Tags: git, docker, deployment

Suppose I have a machine. It can be a single production server, one of production nodes in a cluster, some kind of staging server, a server or a cluster for testing or a developer workstation. Or something different.

Now I want to deliver app to the machine and run it. I can `git pull && docker build`. Or I can just `docker pull`. Or I can `git pull` to another machine and then `scp` code instead. Or I can `scp` docker image tar and then `docker load` instead of `docker pull`.

Sure, Git and Docker are completely different and often used both at the same time. However both have repositories and both can be used to store and deliver code. Even the commands themselves are called the same: push and pull. Docker even has image tags which resemble commits to some limited extend. Because tags also help keep several versions of the app.

There is even a tool for delivery of apps in Production completely based on Git. It's Capistrano. Capistrano `git pull`s the code to anther directory and then redirects a symlink to it in order to deploy.

The question is which reasons to consider when deciding whether to `git pull` or `docker pull` the code to deliver it to a machine?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Docker and Git are 2 completely different technologies.
Git is a Source Control solution, while in docker you can run apps in docker containers. Think of it a sort of 'new' virtualisation technology.
You can use both at the same time hower, no problem.

.... EDIT ...

Docker doesn't keep a copy of your source code. With docker you can build an image based on your source code and put that in a repository. From that image you can run an app in a docker container. So as for workflow basically, you just develop using git, and for deployment you use Docker...

Comment: I know just fine what they are and how they work. I don't know how I should work with them. Both. How exactly. The git+docker workflow.

Comment: Docker doesn't keep a copy of your source code. With docker you can build an image based on your source code and put that in a repository. From that image you can run an app in a docker container. So as for workflow basically, you just develop using git, and for deployment you use Docker...

Comment: That's all I wanted to know. Just put the last sentence to the answer. What was so wrong with my question?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it was unclear. I didn't downvote however....

Answer (score 40):

like the other answers say, git is for version control, e.g. for textfiles.

You build a docker container from a "dockerfile" (which is a textfile).
This "dockerfile" is placed in a directory with many other files and folders.

So if you put this directory, where the dockerfile is located in, into a git repository, then everyone who has access to it, can build the same docker container, with the same configurations and everything.

is that what you mean?

So, the docker container is a "building" and the DOCKER-repository is a market where you can download already built buildings (images), from that you can run a virtualmachine/container. 
 
And the files in the GIT-repository (this is like a big archive for e.g. documents) are the "construction plans". You "share" the different version of the "construction plans" via git, so everyone can build every version of the building.

**Example Workflow:**

In your development environment (your local computer):

1. `git pull` - pull the "construction - instructions" from git repository (e.g. dockerfile)
2. `docker build` - build the docker image from that dockerfile-instructions
3. `docker push myDockerRepo/myDockerImage:latest` - push the newly built docker image into the DOCKER repository (NOT the git-repository)

In your production environment:

1. `docker pull myDockerRepo/myDockerImage:latest` - pull the latest docker image from the DOCKER-repository
2. `docker run` - run a new containerized instance (basically a VirtualMachine) FROM the docker image

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Is building images on Production also ok? Or should rather pull them? When exactly is pulling the images useful?

Comment: Exactly the answer i was looking for! (: Thx

Comment: Since the docker image has been updated with step #2 ( docker build ), should other devs handle the updated image?

Comment: @bresson "building the image" with `docker build` happens locally. Normally you do not apply changes to an image but you apply changes to the "construction - instruction" (step 1), which you `git push` to the central repository, so that other devs can work with it and then -> build images on their local machines

Comment: Just to be clear, "(basically a VirtualMachine)" Docker is not a VM.

Comment: @eli just wanted to be clear, cause I am newbie too, in your steps in docker in prod env, don't we need to pull the code from git too? or we just need to 1. docker pull.. and step 2 ... ?

Comment: In production we don't need the "construction plans" of the container, we just want to get the container, so we can put into place and into action - meaning: we don't need git ( 'git clone' is not necessary) in our production environment, we just need the container (docker pull)

Comment: @eli Why not just use git pull and build the image on production? and not use docker hub at all? sorry i just started to learn docker 2 days ago. Why is dockerhub necessary? Is the image(from git) built on the server different from the one we pushed to dockerhub locally?

Comment: you can do that, sure. But do you build every app you install on your computer, or do you just download and install your apps. I think there are indeed people, that build every app from source. I think the question here is more general - or "whats the best practice". So again: you can do, what you ask, it is completely possible - but in a production environment (meaning company/serious context), (I think!) this would be not adviced. Maybe one practical answer is: Building stuff is more complex/takes more time then just using the endproduct.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me clear some things.

Answer (score 2):

Docker push command, pushes your images to the docker repository, images is not the source code, although may contain source code, and successive pushes for images can override each other and doesn't provide versioning. It is used for pulling images and running containers.
[Docker Repo further info](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/)

On the other hand git push, pushes your source code and other files to the the remote repository. Which is for version controlling. You can pull, fork or pull request to a remote git repository, and can build application from source code. 
[Git Repo further info](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repositories/)

They can be used together, and actually is being used together by many developers. They aim to solve different problems.

Comment: Suppose I am a developer in a team of two developers. I made changes to code. The other developer wants my changes on their machine. We both use Docker and Git. Do I push to git? Or do I push the image? Does he pull the image? Or does he pull from git? Does he ever pull the image from docker repo? Or does he always build it from the dockerfile? Do I ever use Git on production? Or do I only pull the images?

Comment: if you changed your code, you should want it in a version controlling environment, so you should use git to push your code and your colleague can pull your code. And when you want to deploy your project to lets say test environment, you can create an working image and push it to docker repo than from test environment you can pull it and create a container out of it.